# Boto3 list of AWS services

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm currently using the filter option in the get cost and usage method but i can't use service_code to filter, so i need a list of the services, but i can't find one.
So what i need is a method where i can get the name from all the services like this **Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute**.

Here's an example of my code

```
servicio = "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"
billing = boto3.client(
                    'ce', region_name=region, aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
    
                response = billing.get_cost_and_usage(
                    TimePeriod={
                        'Start': str(fecha_inicio),
                        'End': str(fecha_fin)
                    },
                    Filter={
                        'Dimensions': {
                            'Key': 'SERVICE',
                            'Values': [servicio, ],
                        },
                    },
                    Granularity='MONTHLY',
                    Metrics=[
                        'AmortizedCost',
                    ],
                )
```

Comment: Perhaps `list_cost_category_definitions()`?